# Is it good practice to initialize state from route params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building this auction app where there are listings and when the user clicks on one they get navigated to the full details screen using react navigation with params. My question is, is it good practice if I initialize the state using these params then whenever the change in price is triggered from the backend I update the state?

Comment: Having an initial state is required and then updating them once the server responds is standard practice. If the initial state from the nav params satisfied your use case then I don't see an issue using this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it does satisfy the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could also refetch the price when navigating to a new screen or when the purchase button is pressed so that it will stay updated.

For some database, we can also create a listener which automatically updates the price value if there is a change in the back end.